# When using Square e-commerce API for Charge with Card On File is billing address still required to ensure ChargeBack protection?

Tags: square-connect

For a normal charge transaction to a card through the API either the billing address or shipping address plus the email address needs to be provided to ensure that the transaction is covered under the Chargeback Protection rules. However when charging a customer's card on-file the billing address is already on-file with the card information. So can the billing address be omitted in the transaction request and still have the transaction covered under chargeback protection? or does the billing address for the card on file still need to be provided each transaction? Seems redundant if it is already on file. But don't want to lose chargeback protection by omitting.

Answer (score 0):

You should submit the billing address with the charge request. You are right that it is "on file" with the card, but they are used in slightly different ways, so you should include that information with each charge you create. Ideally you'd store that with the customer record so it would be easy to pull out every time you charge.